# React-contenteditable : how to change focus on next filed after pressing Enter

Tags: reactjs, next.js, contenteditable, ref, use-ref

I try to implement focus() after user press Enter on `<InlineEditInput/>` component `<br>`
Tried to use useRef but can't implement it normal `<br>`
Library `react-continentable`

```js
const InlineEditInput = ({ onUpdate, placeholder, data, value, url, name }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const text = useRef(value);
  const onKeyPress = (e) => {
    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  };
  const handleChange = (evt) => {
    text.current = evt.target.value;
  };
  return (
    <ContentEditable
      innerRef={text}
      className={classes.input}
      html={text.current}
      onKeyPress={onKeyPress}
      onChange={handleChange}
    />
  );
};
```

It's my how this Table is look like this:

```js
<Table.Row key={ID}>
  <Table.Cell>
    <InlineEditInput value={`$${original_balance}`}></InlineEditInput>
  </Table.Cell>
  <Table.Cell>
    <InlineEditInput value={`${rate}%`}></InlineEditInput>
  </Table.Cell>
  <Table.Cell>
    <InlineEditInput value={`$${payment}`}></InlineEditInput>
  </Table.Cell>
</Table.Row>
```